# why doesn't arp-scan find any devices when nmap does?

Tags: local-area-network, arp, arch-linux, nmap

When I run `nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24` I get the result:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up (0.16s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.103
Host is up (0.19s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.124
Host is up (0.11s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 124.31 seconds
```

Though when I run `arp-scan 192.168.0.0/24` (the default interface is the one I'm targeting) I get:

```
Interface: wlp6s0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9.5 with 256 hosts (https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan)

0 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9.5: 256 hosts scanned in 1.986 seconds (128.90 hosts/sec). 0 responded
```

Why does `nmap` detect devices on the local network and `arp-scan` doesn't? Is my `arp-scan` not working (broken in some way), or am I missing something? The local network is enabled by an old d-link router.

Comment: I have the opposite issue where `arp-scan` is showing more results than `nmap`

Comment: arp-scan doesn't select the interface from the route, it selects the *first* available interface.